# Formatting floating point numbers in C#: decimal separator always visible

Tags: c#, .net, string, visual-studio

How do I get `12.` from `12` value with standard .NET string formatting? I've tested `0.###` and it does not work.

```
double number = 12;
string.Format("{0:0.###}", number); // returns "12" not "12."

double number = 12.345;
string.Format("{0:0.###}", number); // returns "12.345"
```

Currently I've resolved with string manipulation but is it somewhat possible with standard `string.Format()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you working with `int` values or another data type?

Comment: For now, the answer is `string.Format("{0}.", 12);`. Please clarify what you are doing and trying to achieve.

Comment: @juharr: double, I've edited the code.

Comment: @Wiktor: you are right, I've improved the code now.

Comment: I'm guessing your "string manipulation" is to check for a period after the formatting and add it if it's not there.  If so, that's your best bet IMO.

Comment: @juharr: I check if there is a `.` in the string and if not, I add it.

Comment: Actually, I doubt there is a totally clean way to do it. There should be at least 1 more step: either a check if the number is actually an int, or the `.` adding as you do.

Comment: @Alberto Yeah, I'd just stick with that if it's working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can first check if the double is actually and integer, and if yes, use a simple `string.Format("{0}.", number)`:

```
double number = 12;
if (number % 1 == 0)
    Console.Write(string.Format("{0}.", number));
```

[C# demo](http://ideone.com/0pR0LE)

Comment: As long as it's an integer, otherwise it adds an extra period: `string.Format("{0}.", 0.12);` Up to OP to decide what validation or datatypes he needs to support.

Comment: I think the OP might be working with `double` or maybe `decimal` based on the title even though the example is using an `int` literal.

Comment: I suggest another way now. Check before formatting.

Answer (score 0):

```
double number = 12;
string.Format((number % 1 == 0) ? "{0}." : "{0}", number);
```

Gives `12.`

```
double number = 12.345;
string.Format((number % 1 == 0) ? "{0}." : "{0}", number);
```

Gives `12.345`

Comment: Assuming the OP wants up to 3 optional digits after the decimal using the `{0:0.###}` format as the other option then `12.0001` would give you `12` instead of `12.`